# Delete DynamoDB default cloudwatch alarms

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am new to DynamoDB. While creating a dynamodb table I can see that it also creates some cloudwatch alarms like TargetTraking-TableXX--ProvisionedCapacityHigh.

So my question is can I delete these alarms as it is adding cost. I have tried researching on this but dint find anything. I am afraid to delete this because I am not sure if the AWS itself is using these alarms for the dynamodb maintenance and whether if I delete them will the dynamodb malfunction by any means.

I would also like to know if these alarms are used for scaling up and down in case of autoscaling been enabled or ondemand provisioning is enabled for the dynamodb table.

In my case I am not using autoscaling or ondemand tables so is it fine if I delete those alarms?

Comment: The alarms are used for auto scaling. Did you turn off 'default settings', turn off 'read capacity auto scaling', and turn off 'write capacity auto scaling'? you need to turn off all three to not have an alarm created.

Comment: thanks Ross Williams for your anwer. Do you have any reference articles or anything that I need to present to the team before deleting those alarms. PLease do let me know if you have any such information.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-scaling-for-amazon-dynamodb/ . You can also create a new table with these settings turned off and notice no CloudWatch alarms are created.

Answer (score 1):

The Cloudwatch alarms gets created if autoscaling is enabled for provisioned tables. Whereas On-demand tables are fully managed by AWS and we pay for what we use. If you wish not to have autoscaling then it is ok to delete the alarms or disable them. To revert back the change re-deploy of autoscaling will re-create the alarms.

NOTE: Autoscaling creates 4 read and 4 writes table. The alarms description also says do not EDIT or DELETE the alarm as it affects the autoscaling functionality.